# where are rapsian files located?

Tags: sd-card, filesystem

**short story**

I browse file on SD card from my windows box, but was unable to see any files related to home dir of the new user I create.

**long story**

I tought I lost pi's passwd. my first idea was to move SD card to my windows, browse files up to `/etc/passwd` (`/etc/shadow`) and change password field. (I have recovered the password now, the question is no longer about recovering).

I manage to open `boot.tar.xz` and `root.tar.xz`, but was unable to see my account in /etc/passwd.

So here is the question where are raspian files(*) located ?

are there any ways to find or edit them from windows ?

(*) actual /etc/passwd, home dir of foo user.

(I am also not so sure about actual tag for this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pi has two disk partitions on the SD card (possibly more if you use NOOBS, I don't know).

/boot is where the boot information and kernel image is located.  This partition is formatted as FAT and is understood by Windows.

/ (the rest) is formatted as ext4 and is where everything else resides.  Windows does not understand the ext4 partition.  Some 3rd party software available for Windows might.

Find a Linux box or boot your PC from a "live" Linux CD to gain access to the / ext4 partition.